# Busybox/Qemu Networking

Tags: linux, networking, qemu, busybox

I made a simple Linux Distribution using Busybox that i run in Qemu.
How can i get networking to work?

My Goal is somthing like that:
I type in
`wget google.com`
and it saves the index.html file to the Filesystem.

What do I have to add to my Qemu Command and what do I have to do inside my VM?

My Host is MacOS 14

Comment: Can your question be more specific? What did you try, where are you stuck? There are various guides that explain how to setup networking in initramfs/busybox. Here's an older one in the Gentoo wiki: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Networking https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#DNS

Comment: The Guide in the Gentoo Wiki worked. Thanks